# MVC Sitecore project - how to add key value settings on web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore6

Quiet new to Sitecore hence this basic question to start with...

I've got a MVC Sitecore project up and running. However, I would like to include some simple configuration values on AppSetting of web.config file. From what I read it's not good practice to mess with Sitecore config file.

Could any one please suggest the best practice to add key value on appsettings?

1. Should it go under app_config?
2. If yes, then which folder and what naming convention should I use?
3. And how does Sitecore reads this file on runtime?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my current project I've removed all app settings from the web.config and included them like so:

```
<appSettings configSource=".\App_Config\AppSettings.config" />
```

I then use SlowCheetah ([Which can be downloaded here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5)) to change the settings in the AppSettings.config file if I have environment specific settings.

All changes to the sitecore section of the web.config I add through the include files. You can read more on include files [in this post by John West](http://www.sitecore.net/unitedkingdom/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/05/All-About-web-config-Include-Files-with-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx)